# How to add a "minimize to systray" button in the TitleBar?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, titlebar, custom-titlebar

How I can add a "minimize to systray" near the "minimize" button in the form's TitleBar?

Is easy or hard for a beginner? I need to do it with the WinAPI?

I can't find any info or full example about this.

PS: I'm using VB.NET on Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the nView menu there is something like this, or else you could set the formborderstyle to none, add a button, and add this code:

```
Dim i As New NotifyIcon With {Set properties here}
Me.Hide()
```

Then add an event to the notify icon to make the form show.

EDIT:
I just found this link: [Adding Custom title bar buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172470/adding-a-custom-button-in-title-bar-vb-net).

Comment: Like I've said I wanted to append it near the default buttons, I don't want to set the formborderstyle to none, but thanks.