# How can I place a button on the title bar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, titlebar

I am attempting to make a button that shows a user-menu, as seen in Google Chrome:

[image]

There's no legacy way of doing this, so I've had a look around and I have found that every way of doing this is either outdated or does not work (probably because it's outdated!).

This is the [first link I found](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2007/11/Adding-a-button-on-the-title-bar.aspx), but however it *only* works with Windows Aero off, and probably not with Windows 8, 8.1, or 10, and not very well. The [answer to this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172470/adding-a-custom-button-in-title-bar-vb-net/6172536#6172536) is also essentially the same code:

[image]

*Aero on:*

[image]

I have also found some questions here, but the techniques mentioned do not work. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5739278/2422013) points to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195(VS.85).aspx) which appears to offer some of the functionality I want, but the code however is [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Is this possible in VB.NET without any issues, and if so, how?

This is with VB.NET and Windows Forms, target operating systems are Windows 7 and newer.

Comment: @JasonC This is essentially the same code as in the first link I gave; it doesn't work with Windows Aero, and doesn't display properly in non-Aero mode. Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: Take a look at these 2 links: [Adding caption buttons to the Non-client area on Vista](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2007/09/adding-caption-buttons-to-non-client.html#.VRLAq47LdQQ) [.Net ActiveButtons Library](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2007/03/net-activebuttons-library.html#.VRLA647LdQQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these 2 links:

[Adding caption buttons to the Non-client area on Vista](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2007/09/adding-caption-buttons-to-non-client.html#.VRLLt47LdQR)

[.Net ActiveButtons Library](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2007/03/net-activebuttons-library.html#.VRLLuI7LdQR)

It's been a while since I've used VB.Net, so if you don't mind I'll just add a c# code example (basically I took the example from the first link and tried it, it seems to be working fine)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IActiveMenu menu = ActiveMenu.GetInstance(this);
    ActiveButton button = new ActiveButton();
    button.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    button.Text = "One";
    button.Click += button_Click;
    menu.Items.Add(button);
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button clicked");
}
```

Note: This button doesn't seem to support transparent background, so it doesn't look quite as good as the button in chrome.

Comment: the above link seems to have gone. by any chance do you have the library/sample project for reference ??

Comment: @mrid Not really, but I did find some interesting things when searching... https://www.google.co.il/search?rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&biw=1280&bih=958&ei=7ulVWu-GDceUUZLxoIAC&q=add+a+button+next+to+minimize+&oq=add+a+button+next+to+minimize+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.24094.33027.0.33803.23.18.2.3.3.0.160.2205.0j16.16.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.21.2228...0j0i13k1j35i39k1j0i13i30k1j33i22i29i30k1.0.lzWfbs9vrfY

Comment: Use Wayback Machine to get link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150526051947/http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2007/03/net-activebuttons-library.html#.VWQChXbP3rc

Comment: The latest version of .Net ActiveButtons has been forked. That should help (even though it's been recently archived on GitHub as well) https://github.com/tomaszmalik/ActiveButtons.Net