# Customized Header in Window forms

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

Below shown is the header. I saw it in a application which is not .NET..

[image]

As you can see there are close/Minimize and Maximize buttons and some area at right side designed.

My question is: Is it possible to implement this kind of header in .NET C# or VB.NET ?

Comment: Take a look at this post: [How to draw custom button in Window Titlebar with Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106912/how-to-draw-custom-button-in-window-titlebar-with-windows-forms).

Comment: Also Consider WPF if you wish to dig deeper and explore more options.